# How sort an NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sorting, ios4

I am trying to sort an NSMutableArray for that I am using comparer selector;

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(Product *)someObject {
    return [self.Price compare:someObject.Price];
}

HomeProducts = [HomeProducts sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

I want to sort the same array and donot want to assign to other array.

```
request for member 'Price' in something not a structure or union ....
```

its not recognizing self.Price.

Comment: What object you store in NSMutableArray ? Can you plz provide code for the same ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it


try this one...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it


see this link may be it helps you..

Comment: use NSSortDescriptor

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `compare:` is in the `Product` class then you need to use the console to investigate further.

When the exception occurs, what are the values of `self` and `someObject` - I bet that one of them is either not a `Product` or something that's been released (I think the latter!)

When the crash occurs, you can check the values of self and someObject in the console like this :

```
po self
po someObject
```

(or use the gui to the left of the console).

---

EDIT Answer to comment :

`sortedArrayUsingSelector:` returns an NSArray, `HomeProducts` is an NSMutableArray. Try this instead :

```
HomeProducts = [[HomeProducts sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: I put compare: in Product class and that error removed but now its another warning which cause exception :  warning: incompatible Objective-C types assigning 'struct NSArray *', expected 'struct NSMutableArray *'

Answer (score 1):

How you use it, `compare:` should be a method of `Product`. Try to use a block instead:

```
[homeProducts sortUsingComparator: ^NSComparisonResult (id obj1, id obj2)
{
    return [[obj1 Price] compare: [obj2 Price]];
}
```

or, if `Price` is a simple type, use:

```
[homeProducts sortUsingComparator: ^NSComparisonResult (id obj1, id obj2)
{
    return ([obj1 Price] < [obj2 Price]) ? NSOrderedAscending :
           ([obj1 Price] > [obj2 Price]) ? NSOrderedDescending :
                                           NSOrderedSame;
}
```

FWIW, it is customary to give instance variables, variables, properties, etc. a name starting with a lower case character, and only types start with an uppercase letter.